# Creating a form for a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, has-and-belongs-to-many, form-for

I've read through a lot of posts regarding this topic, but not one actually provides a good answer.
I have a class A and a class B who are related through a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship.

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bs
end

class B < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :as
end
```

What I need is a form for class A showing a selection field with all the instances of B to select. Also, when editing and instance of A, the form should present a list of the related instances of B and a way to mark them for removal.

I have tried creating the list of existing instances by providing a hidden field with the id for each instance of B. And I have created a selection field using the select_tag. The code looked something like that:

```
= form_for @a do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name

  .field
    - @a.bs.each_with_index do |b, i|
      = b.name
      = hidden_field_tag "a[b_ids][#{i}]", b.id
  .field
    = select_tag "a[b_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(@bs, "id", "name")
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

This worked just fine when creating the new instance of A. But when I tried to edit it, there seems to be a problem making the execution fall back to using `POST` instead of `PATCH`. And since with there is now route for `POST` when editing/updating this obviously ended in an exception.

So I wonder if there is any clean way to create the form I need?

Comment: Can you post the full form code?

Comment: Done. Hope it helps. :)